# Cannot find module 'TronWeb' running Nodejs in AWS Lightsail

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail, tron

I have a Nodejs instance running on my local computer, that works just fine when I run command 'node index.js'.
I am trying to port it to an AWS Nodejs instance in Lightsail.
I have installed and set it up identically, but when starting using 'node index.js' command, it fails to find the 'TronWeb' module.
The index.js, package.json, package-lock.json, and the node_modules folder are identical in both instances and I've installed 'tronweb' package using 'npm install tronweb'.
Any thoughts on why 'TronWeb' cannot be located in the Lightsail Nodejs instance?
Below is the first bits of code of the index.js file to give you an idea of what it is.
It throws the error at line 16 "const tronWeb = new TronWeb..."

```
// Initiate request object
const request = require("request");
// Initiate TronWeb object
const TronWeb = require('TronWeb');
const HttpProvider = TronWeb.providers.HttpProvider;
// Full node http endpoint
const fullNode = new HttpProvider("https://api.shasta.trongrid.io");
// Solidity node http endpoint
const solidityNode = new HttpProvider("https://api.shasta.trongrid.io");
// Contract events http endpoint
const eventServer = "https://api.shasta.trongrid.io";
// Private key
const privateKey = "";

// Create instance of TronWeb
const tronWeb = new TronWeb(
    fullNode,
    solidityNode,
    eventServer,
    privateKey
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is really stupid, but I got the answer.

```
const TronWeb = require('tronweb');
```

was all I needed. Not sure why it works fine as

```
const TronWeb = require('TronWeb');
```

on my local machine instance, but it's working fine now.
'tronweb' is the actual package name, but I was assuming that 'TronWeb' was a part of that package. I swear I had tried using the lowercase 'tronweb' before but I guess not. Who knows. Problem solved.